# Obtain type parameters for generic methods in a stack trace

Tags: c#, .net, debugging, diagnostics

I'm accessing the stack frame programatically and pulling out information about the stack which interests me. One such thing is the type parameter for a specific file, if it exists in the trace.

I'm not concerned about fast or maintainable solutions, this isn't going to be production code.

Here's a bit of the code if it helps for inspiration... this makes a collection of strings which are file names and line numbers where the assembly exists in a list defined in ProjectFiles. (Please forgive the conventions and styles, these are not my choice.)

```
var Frames = new StackTrace(true).GetFrames();
var FileNames = Frames
    .Where(Location => ProjectFiles.Any(File => File.Contains(Location.GetMethod().Module.Name)))
    .Select(
        Frame => string.Format("{0}:{1}", Frame.GetFileName() ?? string.Empty, Frame.GetFileLineNumber()))
    .Select(Location => Location.Substring(Location.LastIndexOf("\\", StringComparison.Ordinal) + 1))
    .Reverse();
```

Sample output:

```
Round Trip: SomeUI.cs:583 -> SomeRepository.cs:34, 002ms.
```

Comment: _" type parameter for a specific file"_ - what it is?

Comment: type parameters are the parameters given to an open generic type to close it, such as Query<> -> Query<Person>, in this case the type parameter was the type 'Person'. 

Each frame in a stack trace points to a file. If I search the stack frame for the file "Query.cs", I want to be able to find the generic parameter used by the method referred to in Frame.GetMethod().

Comment: Perhaps type argument is a better name, but you should be able to get the meaning anyway.

Comment: Normally you could use `GetGenericArguments` on `MethodInfo`, but `Frames[0].GetMethod().GetGenericArguments()` do not work as expected probably due to fact that it uses metadata and do not store runtime data. In other ways - not possible.

Comment: You're going to have a hard time doing this as you will need to analyze type hierarchies. For instance, `ThirdLevel<T>` might be declared as `ThirdLevel<T> : SecondLevel<T>` and `SecondLevel<TKey>` which means now you need to figure out where TKey comes from. **Why do you need/want this**?

Comment: I've concluded it's not possible myself but you can never be sure, my knowledge of stack traces and reflection libraries is not the best. If you're sure it's not possible, propose an answer and I'll accept it if nobody else chimes in with a way to do it. I'm going to look into using attributes (which can be obtained from the types) if I don't find a better way.

Comment: @Sprague, the question is - what are you tying to achieve. Maybe there is completely different approach.

Comment: I'm not looking for alternative approaches, the question is fairly specific. I'm sorry. Thanks for your trying to think outside the box, however!